# android update existing child view value/content programmatically

Tags: android

I create a master view MV and a bunch of MV.addView(TextView tv's) (and other widgets, but for simplicity considering only the tv's for now).  All the tv's and the MV etc are created programmatically also (no xml) ... all that works as expected.

I would like to be able update the value/content of the child tv's programmatically in real time  based on user actions.

At the moment I rely on a "kludge":  I get the target child, apply an MV.removeView(), and create a brand new tv with the new .settext(), and then insert the new tv with addView in the location of the old/removed tv.

I do this because I could not figure out how to access the (already added) tvs' values directly.

I have tried using variations of tvexisting = getchild(id), tvexisting.setText("something new"), but no joy.

The (kludge) works, but I would rather be able to change the tv's value directly without the need for "brute force" remove/add views just to change the text/content.  Is such a process available?  Please advise.

Comment: to make life easier.. please provide code if possible..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void addView(TextView tv) {
    MV.addView(tv);
}
void removeView(int index,String newValue) {
    TextView tv = MV.getChildAt(index);
    tv.setText(newValue);
    MV.removeViewAt(index);
    MV.add(tv,index);
}
```

Or if you don't know index you can use ID (But you should to tv.setId(UniqueId) before use);

Comment: Cheers for that.  That's the sort of thing I do at the moment (i.e. the remove/re-add "brute force").  What I was wondering (trying) is some manner of directly accessing the "setText" (etc) of an existing tv (or et, etc).  Separate from the "ugliness" of the brute force approach, it seems much too inefficient when there are a large number of child views to update.

Comment: BTW, I've noticed that internally Android stores much info, as can be seen with Watch during debug.  Those watch's show things like mData etc, which hold the child's content/value etc.  Is there some way to access the info that the Watch can see (e.g. some cryptic hash or something)? ... not sure if this should be a separate question.

Comment: May be need to store tv's in ArrayList and just retrieve and change .I do not know if it will work , but it worth trying.